# What is an exponential function that extends from infinity to $0$ as as $x$ moves from $0$ to $1.$

Tags: functions

Basically, I need a function $f(x)$ (or a family of functions) such that $f(0) = \infty$ and $f(1) = 0.$ The function must decrease from infinity to $0$ for all values of $x$ between $0$ and $1.$ 
I can't think of any.

Comment: f(x)= (1/x)-1 works.  For a family take f_n(x)=(n/x)-n

Comment: And if you need an "exponential" function, use $e^{f(x)} - 1$, where $f(x)$ is rVitale's function. So, $e^{\frac{1}{x} - 1} - 1$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @M.Vinay Oops I didn't read exponential.  Thanks for correcting mine.

Answer (score 0):

Several kinds of functions will work. Since you cite 'exponential' in your question, I would suggest 'logarithmic'. Note that $f(x)=-\alpha\log x$ satisfies your conditions for all positive $\alpha$.